# Which is the best sensor to detect accident in a vehicle eg. A car?

Tags: sensor, embedded, mems

I did some research on this and came across MEMS sensors, there were quite a lot of them, but most of them acted as a gyroscope which would give output for left-right front-back tilts. I want an inertia sensor that can detect sudden change in speed, as in case of an accident, and have a lower sensitivity so that it doesn't trigger on potholes, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange you didn't find them since there are *way* more MEMS accelerometers than gyroscopes around.

Really, it's the same technology only tuned for linear acceleration instead of angular ones. Usually 1 axis (only in one direction) or 3 axes. Often you find 6 axes units (accelerometer + gyro) and even 9 axes ones (typical for phones: accelerometer + gyro + flux gates, gives the magnetic north)

As for sensitivity you'll want a *lower* sensitivity since a pothole gives a lot less Gs than a front collision :D Anyway, it's only a measurement range issue: you can buy 1G sensor for small vibration and, say, 16G sensor for detecting drops to ground. No idea of how many Gs is a car accident.

The output these days is often some kind of digital interface like I2C or SPI; there are however some analog output ones around if you prefer that.

Deciding if it's a collision or a pothole is a filtering issue usually delegated to software.

Comment: Uh to provide some context to how much G's you nee... [quick google](https://www.tdcommons.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3642&context=dpubs_series) shows a 16G is insufficient. A 55 mph crash is >100G according to this source.

Comment: No problem then, for example the ADXL375 has a 200G range and in the application it says "Concussion and head trauma detection; High force event detection". It also does integrated filtering and triggering. Not cheap but fits the requirements

Comment: If you drive a car with a 1 m crumple zone into a wall at 72 kph (20 m/s) then \$ a = - \frac {v^2}{2s} = \frac {20^2}{2 \times 1} = 200 \ \text {m}^2\text {/s} = 20 \ \text g \$. It's all over in 0.1 s.

Comment: There's accelerometers with built-in collision detection, though those are mainly used for consumer electronic purposes. May or may not be useful.

Comment: @Transistor That's the easiest case to detect. But imagine someone getting hit from the side on the freeway, hitting brakes, car possibly spinning around, maybe over the course of 10 seconds from impact to standing still. Now how to filter that out from swift acceleration or an abrupt but controlled stop.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks. I was just responding to "*No idea of how many Gs is a car accident.*" It's only an example.

Answer (score 3):

When your speed changes suddenly, the reason (of a sudden change in speed) is suddenly acceleration change.
So you need an accelerometer sensor not gyroscope sensors because gyroscope detect pitch, roll and yaw angles, not acceleration, although, many of gyroscope modules have an accelerometer sensor onboard.
And to be sure that your sensor and it's dependency circuit is fast enough for your purpose, you can do this :
Assuming your sensor/module is working by 800 Hz :
1/800 = 1250 microseconds.
So your sensor/module send it's data every 1250 microseconds to your microcontroller.
And then you have to calculate your microcontroller-code runtime that are different in every microcontrollers/frequencies and ...etc. but, if it will be (for example) 250 microseconds, your system reaction will be :
1250 + 250 = 1500 microseconds = 1.5 millisecond.
So if an accident happens, 1.5 milliseconds later your system react it.
You can see just an example of accelerometer here :
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12756
It's better to use multi axis accelerometers; more axis, more accuracy. for your purpose:
for example, if you wanna doesn't trigger on potholes, you can ignore vertical axis data or reduce it's effect with a constant coefficient greater than 0 and less than 1, maybe you wanna consider half of it's impact factor so, you can multiply it to 0.5 or ....etc.

Comment: yes +1 for honing in on acceleration not position/orientation or velocity. Of course you could take the derivative of velocity but working directly acceleration already does that job for you. Any sudden peak from an accelerometer tells you something odd is happening.

Comment: @danmcb as i mentioned he can use an accelerometer for that purpose

Comment: yes that's what I am saying +1 to.

Comment: Direction of acceleration is important. Pothole tends to be mostly vertical. A crash, mostly horizontal

Comment: Airbag in fact only fire when the direction is in a certain range: a side collision doesn't deploy the frontal bag, for example

Comment: @dirk-bruere as you know, he can easily use multi axis accelerometer and program a controller to read it's data to have different reactions for each axis & acceleration values

Comment: @lorenzo-marcantonio as you know, he can easily use multi axis accelerometer and program a controller to read it's data to have different reactions for each axis & acceleration values